# How To Create all database backup in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i create backup file for their all database which are available on their SQL Server instance.

Comment: Yes - nice - and the **question is?!?!!**

Comment: Why the upvote and the star?

Comment: I think you've got confused. Stackoverflow is not a code sharing platform, it's a Q&A website. If you want to share your knowledge, you are more then welcome to do that, by answering questions. In this case, you might want to edit your post to a question, and answer it yourself.

Comment: this post is for knowledge sharing

Comment: Great. We love it when people are sharing knowledge. It just needs to be in the form of a question and answer, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to create backup file for their all database which are available on their SQL Server instance, you can use this stored procedure.

You have to create this stored procedure somewhere and give your path where you want to stored all `.bak` file

```sql
-- Use code for creating all database backup
USE [master]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateDBBackup] --create this sp somewhere in your SQL Server
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name 
    DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files 
    DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup 
    DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

    -- specify database backup directory location
    SET @path = 'D:\Backup\' 

    -- specify filename format
    SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT name
        FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
        WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')     

    OPEN db_cursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        SET @fileName = @path + @name + '.BAK' 

        BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  
    END  

    CLOSE db_cursor  
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
END
```